# Kivy drag n drop area is too big

Tags: python, kivy

Reposting this with example code from geeksforgeeks.
I am testing a simple drag and drop function in Kivy with the Drag Behavior module:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html

However, I can't seem to work out how to make the draggable area small. I've tried playing around with the numbers on the drag_rectangle parameters, but the draggable area either doesn't get smaller or just completely disappears for some reason (meaning I can't drag the square). For reference, this is the issue:

[image]

If you run the code in this geeksforgeeks sample the same problem happens so I think it has to something to do with the module itself:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-drag-behavior-in-kivy-widget/

Comment: Maybe the actual size of the widget is larger than the image displayed ? 

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PaulLam I checked, that's actually how big the widget is.

Comment: @ApuCoder The code in the geeksforgeeks link is enough to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

*Referring the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-drag-behavior-in-kivy-widget/) you provided*.

The drag behavior is applied to the widget (here, `Label`) which is triggered when the touch is within `drag_rectangle` (default position is (0, 0)). Here this is set to be the whole widget (`drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height`).

> However, I can't seem to work out how to make the draggable area small...

I think that can be achieved either by restricting the drag rectangle by something like,

```py
drag_rectangle: self.center_x - dp(100), self.center_y - dp(100), dp(200), dp(200) # Within a square of length dp(100) centered at widget's center.
```

Or by limiting the appearance (physical boundary) of the widget using size/size_hint,

Comment: Using dp worked, thank you so much!